# cakephp if ($this->request->is('post')) is true when page loads in add()

Tags: php, cakephp

because of this $this->element('flash_message'); always shows message  UserHub already exists contact admin

Above message appears even if add.ctp loads or refresh page.

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {

}else{
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('UserHub already exists contact admin'));

}
```

Comment: when you refresh the page its a get method so the else part is executed. nothing is wrong, what is that actually you need

Comment: Your `else` statement will run for any non-post request, i.e. loading the page or refreshing it. I suspect what you are actually wanting to do is put that check inside your check for a post request along with another condition.

Comment: its my mistake, what happens session which created for login doesn't kill so when I killed it gives the correct result. I used logout                               $this->Session->delete('userId');
$this->Auth->logout();